# How to register post meta with multi level arrays?

Tags: post-meta, rest-api

I'm tringing to register post meta with object `options` under main object `trim_levels`  to be used with REST API.

```
register_post_meta('vehicle', 'trim_levels', [
  'type'         => 'array',
  'description'  => 'Model trim levels.',
  'single'       => true,
  'show_in_rest' => array(
    'schema' => array(
      'items' => array(
        'type'       => 'object',
        'properties' => array(
          'title'    => array(
            'type' => 'string',
          ),
          'features' => array(
            'type'   => 'array'
          ),
          'options' => array(
            'type'   => 'object',
            'properties' => array(
              'engine'    => array(
                'type' => 'string',
              ),
              'horse_power' => array(
                'type'   => 'string'
              ),
              'transmission' => array(
                'type'   => 'string'
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
]);
```

POST request example with REST API:

```
{
  "title": "Tucson",
  "status": "publish",
  "meta": {
    "trim_levels": [
      {
        "title": "Comfort",
        "features": [
          "Feature 1",
          "Feature 2",
          "Feature 3"
        ],
        "options": [
          {
            "engine": "1,6 T-GDI",
            "horse_power": "177",
            "transmission": "automatic"
          },
          {
            "engine": "1,6 GDI",
            "horse_power": "160",
            "transmission": "manual"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Premium",
        "features": [ 
          "Feature 1",
          "Feature 2",
          "Feature 3"
        ],
        "options": [
          {
            "engine": "1,6 T-GDI",
            "horse_power": "177",
            "transmission": "automatic"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "code": "rest_invalid_param",
    "message": "0 is not a valid property of Object.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

I am struggling to find a way to save the `options` as an associative arrays.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store structured data in a single post meta value, it'll get serialized via PHP which is a security issue, and is extremely difficult to search for values within the structure. It's also usually unnecessary. Post meta values are values in that they need to be strings numbers booleans etc. If you really must store structured data, JSON encode it beforehand into a string, otherwise this approach is incorrect and insecure

Comment: keep in mind that `postmetakey: { foo: 1, bar: 2}` can just as easily be `postmetakey_foo: 1` and `postmetakey_bar: 2`, bundling it all up into a single meta key in the database is unnecessary. You also don't have to rely on `register_meta` to add the values to the rest response, other filters exist that would let you reconstitute it into your preferred structure